# Generating pdf with DomPDF is slow

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf

I'm developing an application in Laravel 5.0, from a view I make a petition to generate a PDF file and download, I'm using DomPDF, for that, I have a controller who manages everything related to the PDF, I have a function:

```
public function invoice()
    {
        $view =  \View::make('invoice')->render();
        $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHTML($view);
        $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    }
```

Then, in the view I made the request using AJAX, this is my code:

```
             $("#dowload").click( function(){

                   $.ajax({
                        url: 'pdf',
                        type: "get",
                        data: {},
                        success: function(data){
                            window.location = 'pdf';
                        }
                    })
                }
```

That is working with no errors, the thing is that it makes it very very slow, and there's no reason because the information displayed in the view *invoice* is static, nothing dynamic, no data processing, nothing and they're only 2 pages!
So, I was checking and I noticed that the slow command is `$pdf->download('invoice.pdf');` so, what should I check?

Comment: Not sure why dompdf itself would be slow, but if the HTML is complex or uses a lot of fonts that could slow things down. Do you have a sample of the HTML?